# How to Insert Select statments in Case clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL knowledge Beginner

I have a below table: ScoreTable

```
Name  Score  Reason  Subject 
a1      0     NULL     NULL
a2      -1    NULL     NULL
a3      -3    fail     Maths
a4      -3    fail     History
a3       0    NULL     NULL
```

I want to write a query which will look some thing like below

```
Select DISTINCT Name, Result, 
   (If Result = -3 
      then Concat(Reason,' ',Subject))As FailedIn)
```

From ScoreTable

Expected Output:

```
Name  Score  FailedIn 
a1      0     0
a2      -1    0
a3      -3    fail Maths
a4      -3    fail History
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to put "0" and a string in the same column.  It is better to use `NULL`.  So:

```
Select Name, Result, 
       (case when Result = -3 then Reason + ' ' + Subject
        end) as FailedIn
```

It is unclear why the last row disappears, but perhaps you want something like:

```
Select Name, min(Result), 
       (case when min(Result) = -3 then max(Reason + ' ' + Subject)
        end) as FailedIn
from table t
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using CASE..WHEN..THEN like below and use minimum result score :

```
SELECT Name, MIN(Result)
   CASE WHEN Result = -3 
        THEN Reason +' '+Subject 
        ELSE Result 
   END As FailedIn
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Name, Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT NAME, SCORE, 
       CASE WHEN SCORE = -3 THEN CONCAT(REASON, ' ' ,SUBJECT )
            ELSE '0'
       END as FAILEDIN FROM ScoreTable